# creating compressed table which is appendable in Greenplum Database

Tags: compression, append, greenplum

I have a few tables created with the following compression logic

```
CREATE TABLE xyz
(
   DATE_HOUR TIMESTAMP, 
   MV CHARACTER VARYING (255), 
   VISITS NUMERIC
)
WITH (APPENDONLY = true, COMPRESSLEVEL = 1, ORIENTATION = column, COMPRESSTYPE = quicklz, OIDS = false)
DISTRIBUTED BY (      
   DATE_HOUR , 
   MV  , 
   VISITS);
```

The tables do get compressed by this logic but the tables are not appendable (because of append only=true). Neither can I add values to this table nor delete from it.

Is there any way this compression logic or any other compression logic that compresses the table and at the same time allows the table to be appendable?

version:"PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.2.3.2 build 1) on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.2 compiled on Jan 10 2013 18:27:37"

Comment: Is this really PostgreSQL? Or are you using Greenplum, ParAccel/Redshift, or something like that? What's the PostgreSQL version? `SELECT version()`?

Comment: Yes,I am using greenplum.

Comment: Fixed your tags. Greenplum isn't PostgreSQL. It's OK to tag your question [tag:postgresql] if it's related to core PostgreSQL features so long as you still mention you're actually using Greenplum. This is totally Greenplum specific, though, and relates to features that do not exist in regular PostgreSQL so I've removed the PostgreSQL tag. (I haven't done much with Greenplum so I can't really help you)

Answer (score 0):

The table you've created this way is appendable, you can easily insert your data into it. But if you are using the version 4.2.x it is not updatable, i.e. you cannot execute UPDATE and DELETE statements over this table.

But if you upgrade to 4.3.x, this table would become updatable compressed table and you would be able to UPDATE/DELETE data in it. But your distribution strategy is really strange, why do you use all the fields for distribution? You should understand that this will prevent you from updating the data as distribution key cannot be updated. For the table you have I'd recommend round robin distribution ("distributed randomly")